# Каким образом можно разбить строку на несколько групп одним выражением?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Хочу разбить `[]` на отдельные группы, как такое сделать?

[image]

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Вы меня не совсем верно поняли- я имел ввиду приведите пример несколько строк, которые вы подаете на вход регулярному выражению, и что вы ожидаете на выходе для этих строк.

Comment: int, string, bool, float, array, также могут быть объекты, но могут быть массивы из всех этих типов int[], int[][] ...

Comment: Пишите синтаксический разбор? Регулярки для этого плохо подходят. И предоставьте, наконец, реальные примеры в формате: на входе это... Должно получиться это ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "в лоб", то просто добавляем избыточные группы, т.к. количество неизвестно (ненайденые группы просто не отображаются). Это жутко неправильно, но срабатывает:

```js
var sText = 'int[Вторая][3][][Последняя]';
var rExp = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\[.*?\])(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?/;
var sResult = sText.replace(rExp, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7');
console.log(sResult);
```

Также, можно получить группы из массива, используя `match`. При этом, несуществующие индексы будут иметь значение `undefined`:

```js
var sText = 'int[Вторая][3][][Последняя]';
var rExp = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\[.*?\])(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?(\[.*?\])?/;
var sResult = sText.match(rExp);
console.log(sResult[1], sResult[3], sResult[10]);
```